# MySQL Restore from a Year Old Backup

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

I have two backups created via [mysqlhotcopy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlhotcopy.html):

1. `backup-before-deletion` from August 7, 2014 and
2. `backup-after-deletion` from February 3, 2016

A deletion event occurred on July 17, 2015 which resulted in the deletion of about 15,000 rows across 7 different tables.

Because this segment of data was hardly ever touched it wasn't noticed until a recent audit.

The good news is the deletion event can be simulated but it would have to be done on the `backup-before-deletion`.

What is the most cost effective way (paid for tools are on the table) to restore the deleted data?

Comment: What does "simulated" mean in this context?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ great question! Updated the description with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

1. Load the data into a different database, or even a different MySQL instance.
2. Locate the deleted rows.
3. Export them in some manner -- `INSERT .. SELECT ..` into another table; `SELECT INTO OUTFILE ...`, `mysqldump`, etc.
4. Load them into your real database.

Cost:  A bunch of your time.